# Search within a table

Tags: javascript, search

I have a table on a page and I need to search within it i.e., like a filter....when i type within the search it should filter the results from the table

Need JavaScript code for the same as not an expert.

`enter code here`   https://jsfiddle.net/jgdqbxhn/

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
    background-image: url("/css/searchicon.png"); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}
```

```html
<p>
    <input
        id="myInput"
        onkeyup="myFunction()"
        placeholder="Search for videos.."
        type="text"
    />
</p>

<table id="myTable"></table>

<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td
                class="mt-bgcolor-dddddd"
                rowspan="5"
                style="vertical-align: top"
            >
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br />
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
                    href="/Archive/eLearning_Library"
                    title="eLearning Library"
                    ><img
                        alt=""
                        class="internal default"
                        height="33px"
                        src="/@api/deki/files/16797/goBack.png"
                        style="width: 112px; height: 33px"
                        width="112px"
                /></a>

                <p class="mt-align-center">&nbsp;</p>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-arial"
                        ><strong
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16823/hot-png-46885.png" /></strong
                    ></span>
                </p>

                <p class="mt-align-center">&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td
                class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1"
                colspan="4"
                rowspan="1"
                style="vertical-align: top"
            >
                <img
                    alt=""
                    class="internal default"
                    height="63px"
                    src="/@api/deki/files/16820/eyes.jpg"
                    style="width: 979px; height: 63px"
                    width="979px"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <strong
                            ><a
                                class="F1"
                                href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Real_Time_Staging"
                                title="documentationcenter.com/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Real_Time_Staging"
                                ><img
                                    alt=""
                                    class="internal default"
                                    height="51.9922px"
                                    src="/@api/deki/files/16778/Real_Time_Staging_-_November_2021.png"
                                    style="width: 97.9948px; height: 51.9922px"
                                    width="97.9948px" /></a
                        ></strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><strong
                                ><strong
                                    ><a
                                        class="F1"
                                        href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Real_Time_Staging"
                                        title="Real Time Staging"
                                        >REAL TIME STAGING - NOVEMBER 2021</a
                                    >&nbsp;</strong
                                ></strong
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <strong
                            ><a
                                class="F1"
                                href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Real_Time_Staging"
                                title="documentationcenter.com/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Real_Time_Staging"
                                ><img
                                    alt=""
                                    class="internal default"
                                    height="51.9922px"
                                    src="/@api/deki/files/16778/Real_Time_Staging_-_November_2021.png"
                                    style="width: 97.9948px; height: 51.9922px"
                                    width="97.9948px" /></a
                            >&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong
                        >
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-arial"
                        ><span class="mt-font-size-14"
                            ><strong
                                ><strong
                                    >&nbsp;<a
                                        href="/@api/deki/files/16781/Real_Time_Staging_-_Presentation_Material.pdf"
                                        target="_blank"
                                        title="https://documentationcenter.com/@api/deki/files/16781/Real_Time_Staging_-_Presentation_Material.pdf?origin=mt-web"
                                        >REAL TIME STAGING -
                                        PRESENTATION&nbsp;</a
                                    ></strong
                                ></strong
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Underwriting_for_New_Business"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Underwriting_for_New_Business"
                            ><strong
                                ><img
                                    alt=""
                                    class="internal default"
                                    height="60.9896px"
                                    src="/@api/deki/files/16783/Reinsurance_Capability.png"
                                    style="width: 93.9974px; height: 60.9896px"
                                    width="93.9974px" /></strong
                        ></a>
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                class="F1"
                                href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Underwriting_for_New_Business"
                                title="Underwriting for New Business"
                                ><strong
                                    >UNDERWRITING FOR NEW BUSINESS - AUGUST
                                    2021</strong
                                ></a
                            >
                        </span></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Underwriting_for_New_Business"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Underwriting_for_New_Business"
                            ><strong
                                ><img
                                    alt=""
                                    class="internal default"
                                    height="60.9896px"
                                    src="/@api/deki/files/16783/Reinsurance_Capability.png"
                                    style="width: 93.9974px; height: 60.9896px"
                                    width="93.9974px" /></strong></a
                        ><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                href="/@api/deki/files/16798/Underwriting_for_New_Business.pdf"
                                target="_blank"
                                title="https://documentationcenter.com/@api/deki/files/16798/Underwriting_for_New_Business.pdf?origin=mt-web"
                                ><strong
                                    >UNDERWRITING FOR NEW BUSINESS -
                                    PRESENTATION&nbsp;</strong
                                ></a
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Data_Transfer_Tool"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Data_Transfer_Tool"
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                height="54.2448px"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16806/Data_Transfer_Tool.png"
                                style="width: 97.9948px; height: 54.2448px"
                                width="97.9948px"
                        /></a>
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                class="F1"
                                href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Data_Transfer_Tool"
                                title="Data Transfer Tool"
                                ><strong
                                    >DATA TRANSFER TOOL -<br />
                                    MAY 2021</strong
                                ></a
                            >
                            <strong><strong>&nbsp;</strong></strong></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Data_Transfer_Tool"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Data_Transfer_Tool"
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                height="54.2448px"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16806/Data_Transfer_Tool.png"
                                style="width: 97.9948px; height: 54.2448px"
                                width="97.9948px"
                        /></a>
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                href="/@api/deki/files/16800/Data_Transfer_Tool.pdf"
                                target="_blank"
                                title="https://documentationcenter.com/@api/deki/files/16800/Data_Transfer_Tool.pdf?origin=mt-web"
                                ><strong
                                    >DATA TRANSFER TOOL -
                                    PRESENTATION&nbsp;</strong
                                ></a
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Rider_Management"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Rider_Management"
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                height="65px"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16809/Rider_Management"
                                style="width: 115px; height: 65px"
                                width="115px"
                        /></a>
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                class="F1"
                                href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Rider_Management"
                                title="documentationcenter.com/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Rider_Management"
                                ><strong>RIDER MANAGEMENT</strong></a
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Rider_Management"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Rider_Management"
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                height="65px"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16809/Rider_Management"
                                style="width: 115px; height: 65px"
                                width="115px" /></a
                        ><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                href="/@api/deki/files/16802/Rider_Management"
                                target="_blank"
                                title="https://documentationcenter.com/@api/deki/files/16802/Rider_Management?origin=mt-web"
                                ><strong
                                    >RIDER
                                    MANAGEMENT-&nbsp;PRESENTATION&nbsp;</strong
                                ></a
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Product_Testing_Workbench"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Product_Testing_Workbench"
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                height="54.0625px"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16810/PTW.png"
                                style="width: 100px; height: 54.0625px"
                                width="100px"
                        /></a>
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                class="F1"
                                href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Product_Testing_Workbench"
                                title="Product Testing Workbench"
                                ><strong
                                    >PRODUCT TESTING WORKBENCH (PTW) - NOVEMBER
                                    2020</strong
                                ></a
                            >
                            <strong><strong>&nbsp;</strong></strong></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <a
                            class="F1"
                            href="/Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Product_Testing_Workbench"
                            title="Archive/eLearning_Library/Client_Learning_Webinar_Series/Product_Testing_Workbench"
                            ><img
                                alt=""
                                class="internal default"
                                height="54.0625px"
                                src="/@api/deki/files/16810/PTW.png"
                                style="width: 100px; height: 54.0625px"
                                width="100px"
                        /></a>
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>

                <p class="mt-align-center">
                    <span class="mt-font-size-14"
                        ><span class="mt-font-arial"
                            ><a
                                href="/@api/deki/files/16804/Product_Testing_Workbench.pdf"
                                target="_blank"
                                title="https://documentationcenter.com/@api/deki/files/16804/Product_Testing_Workbench.pdf?origin=mt-web"
                                ><strong
                                    >PRODUCT TESTING WORKBENCH (PTW)
                                    -&nbsp;PRESENTATION&nbsp;</strong
                                ></a
                            ></span
                        ></span
                    >
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <dl>
                    <dt class="mt-align-center">
                        <img
                            alt=""
                            class="internal default"
                            height="65px"
                            src="/@api/deki/files/16811/RMD.png"
                            style="width: 116px; height: 65px"
                            width="116px"
                        />
                        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    </dt>
                </dl>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please include your Javascript codes to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a script-writing service, and we don't research tools or libraries for you either.

Comment: I added javascript from w3schools but i am sure its not correct

Comment: @CBroe...i would have if I knew it...i came here for help...i thought this was a help forum

Comment: @ikhvjs i added code but not sure if its correct

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want to do with the results of the search? Does the table get updated?

Comment: @Andy....like a filter....when i type within the search it should filter the results from the table

Comment: Which field do you want to filter in the table?

Comment: @ikhvjs...the ones which are in <strong> quotes...for example, real time staging, underwriting for new buisness, data transfer tool and so on...

Comment: @PankajMorajkar, is it allowed to change your HTML format because they are inconsistent. some format are like `<strong>xxx</strong>`, some are like `<a>yyyy</a>`.

Comment: @ikhvjs...yes sure....change it and i can adjust it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An simple example of filtering using classname `filter-items`. You may apply the logic in your codes.

```js
function filterItems(e) {
    const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-items");

    // hide all td
    tds.forEach(td => {
        td.style.display = "none";
    });

    // show filtered items
    items.forEach(item => {
        const word = item.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (word.includes(text)) {
            item.closest("td").style.display = "";
        }
    });
}

document.querySelector("#myInput").addEventListener("keyup", filterItems);
```

```html
<input id="myInput" placeholder="Search for videos.." type="text" />

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="filter-items">123</span></td>
            <td><span class="filter-items">125</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="filter-items">abc</span></td>
            <td><span class="filter-items">abe</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="filter-items">1AB</span></td>
            <td><span class="filter-items">1ac</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @PankajMorajkar, change `querySelectorAll("mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1")` to `querySelectorAll(".mt-bgcolor-ecf0f1")` and only add the class `mt-font-arial` to the nearest tag. You can see my example span is the nearst tag surrounding the text.  I recommend you replace all `strong` to `span` and add class `mt-font-arial` to all these span instead.

Comment: @ikhvjs....this worked....just one more query....the search is case sensitive....how do i make it not to be case sensitive

Comment: @PankajMorajkar, I added case insensitive in codes.

Comment: @ikhvjs...thanks for all your help buddy...you really helped resolve my issue...

Answer (score 0):

I see a static page (not sure what is the datasource). For this static page, you can create a JS function to check all the HTML tags (for each product) and to hide some of them depending on the input from the text field.

I recommend you to start with a very simple example where you apply the javascript function from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

The Fiddle you provided is hard to work with and not uniform. After you have something working you can try to update it to match the design you are searching for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).